# Searchbar UI in ReactJS using Input html

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface, axios

How can I make this kind of UI, where I type something it search/input type in React from the api, i have used axios for fetching the data and I have also used cancel token also. It can also adjust according to my result, suppose my api gives me an array of 10, so it will expand, and if it give me 5, so, it will compress.

```
 var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  var cancel;

  function handleResult(value) {
    if (cancel !== undefined) {
      cancel();
    }
    axios
      .get(
        `https://example.com/search`,
        {
          cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
            // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
            cancel = c;
          }),
          params: {
            q: value,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.hits.hits);
        setList(response.data.hits.hits);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

[image: Amazon.com]

How can I do this?

Comment: hey, you can use any autosuggest library like: Downshift ( This is really good ), or React-Autosuggest ( Link: http://react-autosuggest.js.org/ )

Comment: ok, i will try. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok, i am new to SO, so, will keep this in my mind! Thanks